# Dentro del for, no se me actualiza el JLabel, para que muestre la hora

Tags: java, bucle-for, interfaz-gráfica, try-catch, jlabel

Tengo que hacer la interfaz gráfica de un reloj con la lógica ya establecida, en la consola el cronometro avanza cuando oprimo el botón de la interfaz, pero en la interfaz no se cambia la etiqueta.

Si pongo cualquier texto en la etiqueta dentro del for, no se me cambia la etiqueta en la interfaz igualmente, simplemente necesito que se actualice el jlabel como en la consola, pero no funciona.

A continuación la parte de la interfaz gráfica

```
package IGU;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.System.Logger.Level;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import logica.*;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class Ventana extends JFrame {

    Reloj nuevo = new Reloj();
    private JPanel contentPane;
    String t;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Ventana frame = new Ventana();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Ventana() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lblTiempo = new JLabel("tiempo");
        lblTiempo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblTiempo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblTiempo.setBounds(102, 87, 210, 80);
        contentPane.add(lblTiempo);
        
        
        JButton btnAvanzar = new JButton("Avanzar");
        btnAvanzar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1) {

                    for(int i=0; i<=1000; i++){
                        try {
                            nuevo.correrAdelante();
                            lblTiempo.setText(nuevo.imprimir());
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                        }
                        
                        nuevo.mostrar();

                    }
                
            }
        });
        btnAvanzar.setBounds(173, 163, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnAvanzar);
        

    }
}
```

Me hace falta la parte logica, pero no sé si desde ahí se pueda observar el error, el problema es que no me actualiza el reloj en pantalla, solo en consola, y el jlabel por más que lo intente nos e actualiza

Answer (score 0):

Para modificar el estado de la GUI debes hacerlo desde el hilo (*thread*) donde se ejecuta dicha GUI. Puesto que la acción del botón se ejecuta en otro hilo debes usar el método [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) que te permite modificar el estado de la GUI desde cualquier hilo.

```
for (int i=0; i <= 1000; i++) {
    try {
        nuevo.correrAdelante();
        // Este es el cambio
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> lblTiempo.setText(nuevo.imprimir()));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

    }
                    
    nuevo.mostrar();
}
```