# Problema Java Swing adaptado a POO no se me actualizan los JLabels

Tags: java, poo, java-swing, jlabel

Estoy tratando de hacer un cronómetro con Java Swing y POO pero no se me actualizan los números de los JLabels aunque el método sí que me funciona.
[image: Captura de aplicación]

Clase reloj con sus atributos(horas,minutos,segundos,decimasSegundos y el panel),constructor a 0 y métodos(cronómetro, cuenta atrás y reseteo)
Soy consciente de que el método cuenta atrás debe de estar en un bucle pero lo he puesto sin él porque lo estaba probando.
Hice el debugg y los métodos funcionan así que el problema debe de estar en el lenguaje. He estado investigando y mucha gente lo hace con threads pero la verdad es que yo no entiendo como se implementa eso.

**Clase Reloj**

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Reloj {

    private int horas;
    private int minutos;
    private int segundos;
    private int decimasSegundos;
    Panel miPanelito;

    public Reloj() {
        horas = 0;
        minutos = 0;
        segundos = 0;
        decimasSegundos = 0;

    }


   public void start_crono() {
       miPanelito = new Panel();

       do {      
     miPanelito.decimasSegundos.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(miPanelito.decimasSegundos.getText()) + 1));

           if (miPanelito.decimasSegundos.getText().contentEquals("9")) {
               miPanelito.decimasSegundos.setText("0");
               miPanelito.segundos.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(miPanelito.segundos.getText()) + 1));
           }

           if (miPanelito.segundos.getText().contentEquals("60")) {
               miPanelito.segundos.setText(String.valueOf(0));
               miPanelito.minutos.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(miPanelito.minutos.getText()) + 1));
           }
           if (miPanelito.minutos.getText().contentEquals("60")) {
               miPanelito.minutos.setText(String.valueOf(0));
               miPanelito.horas.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(miPanelito.horas.getText()) + 1));
           }
           if (miPanelito.horas.getText().contentEquals("24")) {
               miPanelito.decimasSegundos.setText(String.valueOf(0));
               miPanelito.segundos.setText(String.valueOf(0));
               miPanelito.minutos.setText(String.valueOf(0));
               miPanelito.horas.setText(String.valueOf(0));

           }

       }while(!miPanelito.horas.getText().contentEquals("24"));
   }


    public void start_countdown(){
        miPanelito = new Panel();

        miPanelito.decimasSegundos.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(miPanelito.decimasSegundos.getText())-1));


            if (miPanelito.decimasSegundos.getText().contentEquals("-1")) {
                miPanelito.decimasSegundos.setText(String.valueOf(9));
                miPanelito.segundos.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(miPanelito.segundos.getText()) - 1));
            }
                //Si los segundos llegan a 60 entonces aumenta 1 los minutos
                //y los segundos vuelven a 0
                if (miPanelito.segundos.getText().contentEquals("-1")) {
                    miPanelito.segundos.setText(String.valueOf(59));
                    miPanelito.minutos.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(miPanelito.minutos.getText())-1));
                }
                if (miPanelito.minutos.getText().contentEquals("-1")) {
                    miPanelito.minutos.setText(String.valueOf(59));
                    miPanelito.horas.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(miPanelito.horas.getText())-1));
                }
                if (miPanelito.horas.getText().contentEquals("-1")) {
                    miPanelito.decimasSegundos.setText(String.valueOf(9));
                    miPanelito.segundos.setText(String.valueOf(59));
                    miPanelito.minutos.setText(String.valueOf(59));
                    miPanelito.horas.setText(String.valueOf(23));
                }


}



    public void reset(){
        miPanelito.decimasSegundos.setText(String.valueOf(0));
        miPanelito.segundos.setText(String.valueOf(0));
        miPanelito.minutos.setText(String.valueOf(0));
        miPanelito.horas.setText(String.valueOf(0));
    }


    public int getHoras() {
        return horas;
    }

    public int getMinutos() {
        return minutos;
    }

    public int getSegundos() {
        return segundos;
    }

    public int getDecimasSegundos() {
        return decimasSegundos;
    }
}
```

---

Clase Panel con sus JPanels, Labels, Buttons y Reloj. No se me actualizan los Labels

**Clase Panel**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Panel extends JPanel{


    //ATRIBUTOS
    protected JPanel panelReloj;
    protected JPanel panelBotones;



    protected JLabel horas;
    protected JLabel minutos;
    protected JLabel segundos;
    protected JLabel decimasSegundos;


    protected JButton btnSeguir;
    protected JButton btnParar;
    protected JButton btnReiniciar;

    protected Reloj miReloj;

    //COMPORTAMIENTO
    public Panel() {

        miReloj = new Reloj();

        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));


        //inicializamos los paneles
        panelReloj = new JPanel();
        panelReloj.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 20);
        panelReloj.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        panelBotones = new JPanel();
        panelBotones.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 500);
        panelBotones.setBackground(Color.red);



        //inicializamos los labels
        horas=new JLabel(String.valueOf(miReloj.getHoras()));
        horas.setFont(new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 50));
        minutos=new JLabel(String.valueOf(miReloj.getMinutos()));
        minutos.setFont(new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 50));
        segundos=new JLabel(String.valueOf(miReloj.getSegundos()));
        segundos.setFont(new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 50));
        decimasSegundos=new JLabel(String.valueOf(miReloj.getDecimasSegundos()));
        decimasSegundos.setFont(new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 50));
        //EL PUNTO Y DOS PUNTOS
        JLabel punto = new JLabel(".");
        punto.setFont(new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 50));
        JLabel dosPuntos = new JLabel(":");
        dosPuntos.setFont(new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 50));
        JLabel dosPuntosX2 = new JLabel(":");
        dosPuntosX2.setFont(new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 50));



        //inicializamos el boton
        btnSeguir = new JButton("Seguir");
        btnSeguir.setBounds(40, 30, 200, 40);
        btnSeguir.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        btnParar = new JButton("Parar");
        btnParar.setBounds(40, 60, 200, 40);
        btnParar.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        btnReiniciar = new JButton("Reiniciar");
        btnReiniciar.setBounds(40, 90, 200, 40);
        btnReiniciar.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        //añadimos en el panel
        this.add(panelReloj);
        panelReloj.add(horas);
        panelReloj.add(dosPuntos);
        panelReloj.add(minutos);
        panelReloj.add(dosPuntosX2);
        panelReloj.add(segundos);
        panelReloj.add(punto);
        panelReloj.add(decimasSegundos);

        this.add(panelBotones);
        panelBotones.add(btnSeguir);
        panelBotones.add(btnParar);
        panelBotones.add(btnReiniciar);

        this.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 195));

        this.setVisible(true);


        btnSeguir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                miReloj.start_crono();
            }
        });

        btnParar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                miReloj.start_countdown();
            }
        });

        btnReiniciar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                miReloj.reset();
            }
        });


        }


}
    //FIN CONSTRUCTOR
```

---

Clase MainFrame con su Panel

**Main Frame**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    //ESTADO
    //panel
    protected Panel panel1;


    //COMPORTAMIENTOS
    // Constructor
    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);  //Para que se muestre el título

        // Crear el frame.
        this.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Creamos los paneles y le ponemos un layout
        panel1 = new Panel();
        this.add(panel1);
    }
}
```

Comment: En lugar de hilos considera usar un [*temporizador*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) que se ejecute cada segundo, en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/453394/detener-un-frame-tras-abrirse-otro-frame/453427#453427) tengo un ejemplo de su uso.

Comment: Creo que es el mismo problema que plantea esta pregunta> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/568473/dentro-del-for-no-se-me-actualiza-el-jlabel-para-que-muestre-la-hora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lore, tu código tiene algunos problemines:

```
miPanelito.decimasSegundos.setText( String.valueOf(0) );
```

no tiene sentido hacerlo de esta manera setText( "0" ) es lo mismo.

modifica el constructor para que reciba un "Panel", ya que sino, estas usando un "Panel" que no es el que esta cargado en el frame.

```
public Reloj( Panel miPanel ) {
    miPanelito = miPanel;
```

Y debes borrar miPanelito = new Panel(); en los métodos "start_crono" y "start_countdown" y por supuesto, tambien cambiar en la clase Panel, la instanciación de esta clase.

```
miReloj = new Reloj( this );
```

En el método "start_crono", el "do-while" está de más, de hecho, así como está el while negando la condición, lleva a un bucle infinito.

El método "start_countdown", funciona bien, empieza desde "23:59:59:9", si quieres algo distinto debes crear una función que inicialize a un valor distinto de cero.

A mi entender, deberías tener 5 botones, "parar", "seguir", "cuentaAtras" y "cuentaAdelante" y "reset".

Ahora vamos con lo picante:

para ejecutar una función a intervalos de tiempo regulares, podemos usar la clase "Timer" de swing (ojo con el import), para esto debes agregar la variable "Timer timer;" en la clase Reloj, dentro del constructor la instancias de la siguiente manera:

```
timer = new Timer( 100, (ActionEvent e) -> {
    run();
});
```

De esta manera logras que se ejecute "run" en los intervalos declarados, en este caso es el "100".

tambien debes declarar la variable "int funcion = 0", que usaremos para saber que método se ejecuta.  Debes agregar los siguientes métodos:

```
void cuentaAdelante() { 
    funcion = 0;
    timer.start();
}

void cuentaAtras() { 
    funcion = 1;
    //set();
    timer.start();
} 

void run() {
    if( funcion == 0 ) {
        start_crono();
    }
    else if( funcion == 1 ) {
        start_countdown();
    }
}

void parar() {
    timer.stop();
} 

void seguir() {
    timer.start();
}
```

El métodos "cuentaAdelante" y "cuentaAtras", son llamados por los listeners de la clase Panel, setean el valor de "funcion", para que el método run, "sepa" cual de los métodos debe ejecutar y ponen el hilo en marcha con "timer.start".
El método run, sencillamente ejecuta la función adecuada en base al valor de "funcion".

Parar y seguir... es obvio lo que hacen.

En la clase Panel realiza las siguientes modificaciones:

```
btnCuentaAdelante.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        miReloj.cuentaAdelante();
    }
});  

btnCuentaAtras.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        miReloj.cuentaAtras();
    }
});

btnReiniciar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        miReloj.reset();
    }
});

btnSeguir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        miReloj.seguir();
    }
});  

btnParar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        miReloj.parar();
    }
});
```

Debes agregar las declaraciones de los botones nuevos y toda su configuración.
Algo de info sobre la clase Timer:
https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/java/swing-timer-in-java/

espero haberte ayudado.